# I want to update the data with php

Tags: php, html, database, pdo

I want to update the data with PHP.when I click the button, the page refreshes and the update does not occur. How to correct

**MY CODES:
File Name:Contact_settings**

```
<form action="../netting/islem.php"  method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Gsm Number<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <input type="text"  name="ayar_tel"  value="<?php echo $ayarcek['ayar_tel'] ?>" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
    </div>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div align="right" class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
    <button type="submit" name="iletisim" class="btn btn-success right">Güncelle</button>
 </div>
  </div>
```

FİLE NAME:islem.php

```
if(isset($_POST['iletisim'])){

$ayarkaydet = $db->prepare("UPDATE ayar SET
      ayar_tel       =:ayar_tel,
      WHERE ayar_id=3
  ");
$update = $ayarkaydet->execute
(
    array(
        ':ayar_tel'       => $_POST['ayar_tel'],

    )
);
```

Comment: Voting as a typo `:ayar_tel,` < for the trailing comma which should not be there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have an error in your code

must be like this

```
if(isset($_POST['iletisim'])){

    $ayarkaydet = $db->prepare("UPDATE ayar SET ayar_tel =:ayar_tel WHERE ayar_id=3  ");
    $update = $ayarkaydet->execute (array(':ayar_tel' => $_POST['ayar_tel']));
}
```

I delete two commas in your sql where and in your execute array and add a close } for the if sentence.